# nested for loops with C preprocessor?

Tags: c, preprocessor

I would to design a sequence of instructions with indices inserted inside the instructions.

For example, I would write :

```
#define STUFF(I,J) i + j;
#FOR i = 0 to 4
   #FOR j = 0 to 2
       STUFF(i,j)
   #ENDFOR
#ENDFOR
```

And the preprocessor would output this :

```
0 + 0;
0 + 1;
1 + 0;
1 + 1;
2 + 0;
2 + 1;
3 + 0;
3 + 1;
```

Is this a possible behaviour? I'm okay with stopping at nested loops of depth 2.

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: educational purposes. instruction level parallelism to be specific. i want to unroll C loops and make use of superscalar processors

Comment: I would recommend manual unloop. Preprocessor is not readable and a pain to debug. Remember: write once, read multiple times.

Comment: that was just a tiny example... when i have to manually unloop at 16x16 loop.......

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost Preprocessor Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) provides `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`, which does what you want.

Although part of Boost, this library is header-only, so it does not require installation other than copying the header files, and is specified to work both with C and with C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `#FOR` in the C preprocessor, but you can use nested macros to make it somewhat more tolerable:

```
#define STUFF(I,J) i + j;
#define STUFF_I(I) STUFF(0) STUFF(1)
#define STUFF_IJ STUFF_I(0) STUFF_I(1) STUFF_I(2) STUFF_I(3)

STUFF_IJ
```

expands to:

```
0 + 0; 0 + 1; 1 + 0; 1 + 1; 2 + 0; 2 + 1; 3 + 0; 3 + 1;
```